# Twitter oauth search not working

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am currently using twitteroath library https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth to do a search of tweets.

This is my code:

```
 require_once('twitteroauth.php');

 function getConnectionWithAccessToken($oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret) {
 $connection = new TwitterOAuth(X, Y,       $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
 return $connection;
}

$connection = getConnectionWithAccessToken(Z, K);

$author = "cosmopoulos";

$response = $connection->get('search/tweets', array('q' => $author));
```

I don't get any results. Am I authenticating incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php
require_once('twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php');
include('config.php');
$connection = new TwitterOAuth($CONSUMER_KEY, $CONSUMER_SECRET, $ACCESS_TOKEN , $ACCESS_SECRET);
$content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');
$author = "cosmopoulos";
$tweets = $connection->get("search/tweets", array("q" => $author));
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($tweets);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```